# What are my options for strong CSS development against Safari

Tags: css, safari

I can use FireFox and FireBug, in a pane, I can open a .css file, in real time, as I make edits, I can see those edits reflected in FireFox.  This is a very handy and valuable feature.

Without starting a debate over browsers, I would love to be able to do the same thing in Safari. My far too small display on this laptop aside, real time development of css helps me move things along at a very nice pace.

While I am near certain any input manager for Safari would not officially be supported, I am OK with that.  I have been playing around with the "Web Inspector", but as far as I can tell, this will not fit the bill for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this on a Mac? You can give [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/) a try.  It's not free, but has a built in webkit preview

Comment: ...and it updates instantly whenever you change the CSS! I definitely second CSSEdit—it's one of my main web development tools. (And yes, I didn't even think to mention it in my answer!)

Comment: I can do that now in TextMate.  The trouble is, that means I have to pull all the files down locally, and if it is server side stuff, it can be a real pain to set up a dev environment locally and remotely to be identical.

With the way FireBug works, it does all the downloading and parsing in the browser, and you work on the already parsed and done work.

Thanks, I will give it a look though.

Comment: CSSEdit has a stylesheet override feature where you can view a remote page and 'override' it with another stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest version of [webkit](http://webkit.org/), it has a much more powerful version of Web Inspector which you can use side by side with the latest Safari (two browsers open) to debug Safari.

Comment: Is it the same more or less as the one in version 4?  If that is the case, I can not find a way to edit CSS in real time, though I could be missing it, which is why I was asking here.

Comment: There's no easy firebug way to edit css in web inspector, that has been filed as a bug though.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Safari are you using? I'd recommend getting Safari 4 Public Beta, which has a brand new Web Inspector that allows you to edit the DOM real-time (I'm not sure whether you can actually edit a CSS file with it, however).

Steve

Comment: I am using Safari 4, hacked a little to put the tabs back where they belong. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).

Comment: Never even knew about this.  While I have a feeling it will not be robust enough, I do appreciate you letting me know about it.